# Migrating from Weblogic 11 to Weblogic 12, getting ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, migration, ejb, weblogic, weblogic12c

We are migrating an Application consisting of several ear files from Weblogic 11 to Weblogic 12. Three of the ear files are running well, when we deploy the 4th it throws a ClassNotFoundException on startup.

Two of the three running ears aren’t important in this regard. So, the situation is that A.ear runs fine, B.ear fails to start.

B.ears pom.xml refers to a module of A.ear as dependency with provided and ejb-client, and using maven-ear-plugin it refers to the module as ejbClientModule.

Due to the maven-ear-plugin, a jar is created in B.ear mirroring the module in A.ear, adding “-client” to its name, but it only contains a subset of classes from the module in A.ear.

One of this classes is derived from the class the ClassNotFoundException refers to.

The application worked this way on Weblogic 11.

Can somebody please tell me how to fix this problem and make the application work on Weblogic 12?

Comment: In B.ear you are using a module from A.ear. And the scope is provided. And you are getting ClassNotfoundException .. right ? This is your issue ?  This exception is coming during Deployment time. This is not a runtime exception. So you need to have the same package named classes from A.ear that you will be using in B.ear during deploy. Remove the provided scrope, let the dependant module be created inside lib folder and then deploy the appl B.ear and check.

Comment: I tryed it, the error is still the same. I tryed putting the file in B.ear by hand to see what other problems pops up. Then it is missing another file, and that error is unchanged by changing the scope too. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Pls give a snapshot of ur old working EAR module expanded and that of the new EAR module which is faulty. Give ur pom.xml as well. And show me the error that u get. also the deployment log with exception stack trace. Give a complete picture, else it will be difficult to tell.

Answer (score 0):

As we figured, such deep connections between ear files are not allowed in weblogic, even in weblogic 11, the classloader hierarchy is as per oracles documentation unable to find the ancestor class in another ears jar. That it was working in weblogic 11, seems to be an error, that has been fixed in weblogic 12.

The solution for us was to put the two ear files into one.